# Couldn't install rails in windows 8.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, rubygems, sslv3

I had install ruby -version 2.2.4p230 but unable to install rails by using **gem install rails**. After writing this line in CMD the error saying **Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (>= 0), here is why:
  Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)**

I had searched a lot about this but didn't get anything useful for me. Please do a help for installing the rails.

Comment: RoR development on windows is a nightmare. Even with the Windows Dev package you will almost definitely run into lots of errors that have nothing to do with your code. Duel boot with with some form of Linux and save yourself a world of headaches

Answer (score 0):

Exact same error. Another poster suggested this link. http://guides.rubygems.org/ssl-certificate-update/ but it didn't work for me.

ruby -v
ruby 2.2.5p319

gem --version
2.4.5.1

gem install rails
Error: could not find a valid gem 'rails' <>=0>, here is why: Unable to download data from  **links removed not enough rep to post***  This page suggests a manual certificate fix which I will try next http://guides.rubygems.org/ssl-certificate-update/#background  I am thinking the pem file is not located correctly.

Comment: That was it for me. Doing a manual install of the PEM file let me execute gem install rails   For the first time ever.. :-)

Comment: After a long wait, now switched to **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS** with dual boot. Feeling relax & full of enthu, after-all now I can do whatever I want with _Rails + Ubuntu_ -- Great Combo..